# Placing the elements inside the div in a straight line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="identity1">
  <p>
  Hai
  </p>
  <p>
  How are you
  </p>
  <img src="http://lmsotfy.com/so.png" width="200px">
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
 #identity1
  {
    float:left;
  }
```

I want all the elements inside the div should be placed side by side. I want the output something like this.

> Hai How are you (and the image)

How to do this?
I have attached the demo file [here](https://jsfiddle.net/be0fxuyr/)

Comment: So why are you using paragraph elements if you want it to be in one line? Seems like you should have one paragraph around all the elements and the  elements inside should be spans if you need them.

Comment: Indeed...this looks like you should be using `span` tags.

Comment: `Span` or `label` will be an option

Comment: `label` would not be appropriate unless this is a `form` and has `input`s

Answer (score 1):

You are applying float:left; to the whole div. If you want to apply to the `<p>` tags then do:

```
 #identity1 p
  {
    float:left;
  }
```

Or you could give the p and img tags the class of identify1 instead to make them all float left.

Or you could do this to apply float left to all child elements using *:

```
#identity1 *
{
  float:left;
}
```

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/rzwscvke/
You might also then want to add margins to all too or you could just use display:inline or display:inline-block depending on the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` for p and img tag

```
 #identity1 p,
 #identity1 img {
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
#identity1
{
  float:left;
}
p{
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
display:inline
```

for p and img tags.

I have pasted the code in https://jsfiddle.net/v121v6kL/

Answer (score 0):

just make all of them inline-block

```css
#identity1 * {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="identity1">
  <p>
  Hai
  </p>
  <p>
  How are you
  </p>
  <img src="http://lmsotfy.com/so.png" width="200px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```css
#identity1 p {
  float:left;
  margin:0px 2px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="identity1">
  <p>
  Hai
  </p>
  <p>
  How are you
  </p>
  <img src="http://lmsotfy.com/so.png" width="100px" height="40px;">
</div>
```